# Azure Eclipse Plugin - creating an azure deployment project

Tags: eclipse, azure-java-sdk

I have installed, on my Windows 8.1 laptop with Eclipse Kepler, the Eclipse Microsoft Azure Plugin. After creating a Dynamic Web Project I try to create a "New Azure Deployment Project" but I get an error message: "Error creating the project".

What can cause this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I think I've found the solution. The problem was that I had my eclipse folder in "C:\Program Files\eclipse". I think by default you need admin rights to write to this directory (and subdirectories). So there occur errors during the installation of the azure sdk (but you don't see them, at least I didn't).

## My solution was:

1. Grant your local user Full Permissions to the "C:\Program Files\eclipse"-folder.
2. Uninstall the azure plugin in eclipse (Help --> Installation Details --> Installed Software --> select all items you previously installed for the azure plugin --> uninstall ...)
3. Restart eclipse
4. Install the azure plugin again.

I hope this also works for you.